# How can I get a list shows which add-ons are enabled by user?

Tags: add-on, customization

I want to know which add-ons in Blender 2.79 are enabled by me.

Comment: Do you want to get the enabled add-ons, excluding those that are enabled by default, or all add-ons that are currently enabled?

Comment: @RobertGützkow Yes, excluding those add-ons enabled default .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Blender's Python API allows to get the currently enabled add-ons, without any differentiation of what/who enabled them. Therefore it's not possible to distinguish between add-ons that have been enabled by default, by the user or by another add-on/script. You may however compare the currently active add-ons to the ones that are known to be enabled by default and only use those that are not it the default list.

**Blender 2.79**

The enabled add-ons can be access through the user preferences [`bpy.context.user_preferences.addons`](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/bpy.types.UserPreferences.html#bpy.types.UserPreferences.addons).

```
import bpy


for addon in bpy.context.user_preferences.addons:
    print(addon.module)
```

The add-ons that are enabled by default are:

```
io_scene_3ds
io_scene_fbx
io_anim_bvh
io_mesh_ply
io_scene_obj
io_scene_x3d
io_mesh_stl
io_mesh_uv_layout
io_curve_svg
cycles
```

Therefore a solution that excludes them could look like this:

```
import bpy


default_addons = {"io_scene_3ds",
                  "io_scene_fbx",
                  "io_anim_bvh",
                  "io_mesh_ply",
                  "io_scene_obj",
                  "io_scene_x3d",
                  "io_mesh_stl",
                  "io_mesh_uv_layout",
                  "io_curve_svg",
                  "cycles"}


for addon in bpy.context.user_preferences.addons:
    if addon.module not in default_addons:
        print(addon.module)
```

**Blender 2.8x**

The enabled add-ons can be access through the preferences  [`bpy.context.preferences.addons`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Preferences.html#bpy.types.Preferences.addons).

```
import bpy


for addon in bpy.context.preferences.addons:
    print(addon.module)
```

The add-ons that are enabled by default are:

```
io_anim_bvh
io_curve_svg
io_mesh_ply
io_mesh_stl
io_mesh_uv_layout
io_scene_fbx
io_scene_gltf2
io_scene_obj
io_scene_x3d
cycles
```

Therefore a solution that excludes them could look like this:

```
import bpy


default_addons = {"io_anim_bvh",
                  "io_curve_svg",
                  "io_mesh_ply",
                  "io_mesh_stl",
                  "io_mesh_uv_layout",
                  "io_scene_fbx",
                  "io_scene_gltf2",
                  "io_scene_obj",
                  "io_scene_x3d",
                  "cycles"}


for addon in bpy.context.preferences.addons:
    if addon.module not in default_addons:
        print(addon.module)
```

Comment: But that won't get add-ons specifically enabled by the user, will it? It will also get add-ons that come pre-enabled? (I haven't tested this yet, just wondering.)

Comment: @RayMairlot Since users also have the ability to disable and re-enable the default add-ons, it's not possible to distinguish the default activated and user activated add-ons. You can only retrieve a list of currently active add-ons, how that state came to be is unknown.

Comment: So shouldn't that be in the answer as I think that is what the user is asking for?

Comment: @RayMairlot Updated the answer.

Comment: IMO Could go closish to an estimate.  The default enabled addons is a set of about 8 import / export and cycles render.  (disregarding that user may have disabled then reenabled) Any addon enabled that resides in the user addons folder could be put in the user enabled camp.

Comment: @batFINGER Sure we can build some heuristics to get an answer that's likely good enough. I'm not sure though if Basara Kubikiri definitely wants to exclude them.

Comment: Kinda read this the same way as Ray, but wasn't sure.  Good idea to seek clarification above.

Comment: So now I can get an add-on list from a fresh-installed Blender, then compare it with the list I got from my current Blender install. I think by doing this, I could get the answer I wanted?

Comment: @BasaraKubikiri Yes that would be a way to solve this

Answer (score 0):

Enabled addons list for blender 2.79 in human-readable format:

```
enablist = [addon.module for addon in bpy.context.user_preferences.addons]
for addon in addon_utils.modules():
    if addon.__name__ in enablist:
        print ('{name} {ver} {mod}'.format(
            mod = addon.__name__,
            name = addon.bl_info['name'],
            ver = ''.join([str(v) + '.' for v in addon.bl_info['version']]).rstrip('.')))
```

Update for 3.0+:

```py
import addon_utils
enablist = [addon.module for addon in bpy.context.preferences.addons]
for addon in addon_utils.modules():
    if addon.__name__ in enablist:
        print ('{name} {ver} {mod}'.format(
            mod = addon.__name__,
            name = addon.bl_info['name'],
            ver = ''.join([str(v) + '.' for v in addon.bl_info['version']]).rstrip('.'))) if 'version' in addon.bl_info else None
```