# Reset all add-ons

Tags: add-on

I made a great mistake that **I selected all addons in blender**
Without knowing the uses of that add-ons. Now I'm confusing all are looking like new. Some tabs are new. For that I unseleced all add-ons now I don't have cycles render and many useful options. Please help me to reset all add-ons which presented when I open first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try resetting Blender with **"Factory Reset"**.This would reset Blender to its initial installed state and hopefully also activate the uninstalled addons.
**Note** other settings like user defined hotkeys would be lost if this approach is followed.
[image]

Comment: Thank you, wow I didn't see that factory reset. Thanks it worked

Comment: Should make the OP  aware that this does not automatically save  new  startup file if they saved addon prefs beforehand (this is a new default feature in 2.8).. See [docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/getting_started/configuration/defaults.html#loading-factory-settings) for more info. In other words, this is a temporary fix unless new prefs are saved.

Comment: Didn't know about this.

Answer (score 4):

**Disable non default addons**

Further to [How can I get a list shows which add-ons are enabled by user?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/166371/how-can-i-get-a-list-shows-which-add-ons-are-enabled-by-user)

Test script Disables all non-default addons (not listed as default) and saves user preferences.

```
import bpy

default_addons = {"io_anim_bvh",
                  "io_curve_svg",
                  "io_mesh_ply",
                  "io_mesh_stl",
                  "io_mesh_uv_layout",
                  "io_scene_fbx",
                  "io_scene_gltf2",
                  "io_scene_obj",
                  "io_scene_x3d",
                  "cycles"}

# enable defaults                  
for addon in default_addons:
    bpy.ops.preferences.addon_enable(module=addon)


for addon in bpy.context.preferences.addons:
    if addon.module not in default_addons:
        bpy.ops.preferences.addon_disable(module=addon.module)
        
bpy.ops.wm.save_userpref()
```