# Create List of Activated Addons and 3rd-Party Installed Addons in Blender

Tags: python

Sorry if this has been asked before but I certainly couldn't find what I was looking for!

I just want to be able to locate or create a file that clearly shows me which native Blender Addons I have "activated" and what 3rd-Party Addons I have installed.

Ideally I want a text file so that when i install a NEW version of Blender I can reinstall (or re-activate) the Addons that I like and need!

Regards and thanks in advance

Ivan Flack
Cookstown, N. Ireland

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-installed-addons-using-the-api?rq=1 any good? - Note that installing a new version of Blender will pick up the settings from a previous version automatically including activated addons. (This assumes that you haven't deleted the settings from the previous version of course!)

Comment: Thanks John...I looked at that but am none the wiser...can't seem to get it to work at all!

Comment: Its' possible that the python code needs to be changed for more recent Blender versions since that posting was last updated 10 years ago but I'm afraid I don't know Blender's API so can't help with that one.

Comment: There's a more up to date posting here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/166371/how-can-i-get-a-list-shows-which-add-ons-are-enabled-by-user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is taken from the posting I mentioned in the comments above:

Click the <kbd>Scripting</kbd> workspace in the top toolbar then click the <kbd>New</kbd> button in the R/H text editor window and copy and paste the code below into the window.

```
import addon_utils
import bpy
enablist = [addon.module for addon in bpy.context.preferences.addons]
for addon in addon_utils.modules():
    if addon.__name__ in enablist:
        print ('{name} {ver} {mod}'.format(
            mod = addon.__name__,
            name = addon.bl_info['name'],
            ver = ''.join([str(v) + '.' for v in addon.bl_info['version']]).rstrip('.'))) if 'version' in addon.bl_info else None
```

If you click the right-facing <kbd>Run Script</kbd> triangular icon in the window header you can then Use Blender's <kbd>Window</kbd> > <kbd>Toggle System Console</kbd> menu to see the active addons in the console window.

Comment: Many thanks once again John...I'll give it a go when I am next on the PC!

Comment: Thanks again John...works just fine...now I just need to put it into Serpens and get it to print out a list! Fun, fun...fun!

Comment: Glad to hear it! As one of the other posting says there's probably no way to differentiate between built-in and external addons but at least you have a list of enabled ones now! Please check the option beside my answer to flag it as correct. Thanks.